# .devcontainer featuring multiple dockerized tools

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

I made a `.devcontainer` that uses a pretty long custom `Dockerfile` that integrates all the tools I need : `inkscape`, `python`, `tex-live`, `draw.io`, `pandoc`...

This solution isn't very optimum because instead of using official Docker images for each tool, I made an aggregate image not very KISS.

I would rather prefer to have all my tools described in the way:

```
inkscape=docker run inkscape --rm -v $(pwd):/app -w /app minidocks/inkscape
```

Then, be able to use them from my main container. This would allow updating each tool independently without rebuilding the main container.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Could you volume mount to the tools you wanna use? Then you don't need to install them a gain for each container.

Comment: The basic idea is to not depend on the host architecture. That’s why it should run dockerized

Comment: But you do a volume mount in your example `inkscape=docker run inkscape --rm -v $(pwd):/app -w /app minidocks/inkscape`, isn't it intentional?

Comment: Yes it is, I didn’t yet your point then

Comment: Then it will depend on the host architecture as it is mount from the host. No? Which seems conflict to your previous point.

Comment: The storage yes, but the development tools aren’t